# How attach resolvers for each field in Appsync and query after

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I need you help.

Currently I'm working with AppSync, and I know how to create resolvers, pipelines, etc. But I don't know how to use the fields resolvers. For example, I attach a resolver for each field of my type, because some fields have different sources, but if I want to query the "type", I need to create a new resolver for the query operation "getCustomer"? what is the correct way to use the field resolvers?

**Please if possible an example of each resolve in VTL.**

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should create a resolver on the `getCustomer` query also.
This will be performed first and the results will be available in the context when resolving the field level resolvers.

[image: Schema]

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your answer. Do you have an example of getCustomer resolver reusing each field resolver? My first goal is not to invoke services when I don't need some fields.

Comment: Can you clarify that question?

In this example, `OtherDataSource` will only be invoked if you request `blocks` back when calling `getCustomer`

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your answer. I want to know the BaseDataSource resolver, because I don't know how to write a getCustomer resolver without id, name and blocks functions resolvers, currently I only have a getCustomer pipeline, But my logic say me that is not the best approach, I want that each field be responsible of your own data.